# How can I submit a Django formset within python code?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

**Background.** We want our users to check if the metadata we read out of several images is correct.
Therefore, we show the retreived data in a formset to let the user check everything.
In case the metadata has errors (that happens) we would like to display them as form errors here.

**Problem.** To obtain the error messages we need *bound* forms. Feeding our various data into a bound `ModelFormSet` and taking care of the `ManagementForm` is ... not so simple. With the unbound version everything works fine.

**Idea.** If we could produce an unbound form and *submit it within the python code*, that would be a simple way to get the POST data we need to create the bound form.

Comment: Do you actually need to submit the form? or just check if it's valid?

Comment: @Brandon I just need to check if it's valid, but hoped I could do it without caring about the ManagementForm data.

Comment: Well, nothing says you have to use a formset. You can always just use a list of form instances and it will basically accomplish the same thing. Formset just gives you some convenience methods.

Comment: It's super easy to just loop over a list of form instances and call `.is_valid()` on each one.